# Drupal modules calling Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, drupal

working on an Drupal architecture where I'd like to have a stand alone Drupal/DrupalCommerce installation with product definition based on content coming from an apart Oracle DB.

Does anybody have experience in integration between Drupal and ORacle.
I'm not speaking about replacing MySQL by ORacle but by using ORacle content in specific modules. 
What is the best connections options : XML-RPC, REST, WebServices/SOAP ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to define the Oracle database as a secondary database in the Drupal settings file?

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php
- http://drupal.org/project/oracle

If you manage to connect, you could then write a custom module to switch to the secondary database, retrieve the data from the Oracle database and bring it into the Drupal context.

I would like to find out if you found other solutions.